# Low JsHeapSizeLimit in Chrome 118 on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, chromium

We have a customer where all the users are on same hardware - MAC with 8GB installed memory.

For ~70% of the users, JsHeapSizeLimit is 2.17GB only. For rest of the users, its 4.29GB. We are trying to understand how JsHeapSizeLimit is allocated to the browser.

What factors contributes to this JsHeapSizeLimit allocation to chrome browser? Is there any way for us force this to be 4.29GB for all of the users?

Brief context:
Because of an elusive memory leak, users are facing Out of memory Aw snap errors. While we investigate and plug the memory leak, we are looking for options on immediate relief for our users. One of the promising options seems to be higher JSHeapSizeLimit as this means that users can work twice as longer.

Tried going through the official docs but surprisingly there is very little to no details on how JsHeapSizeLimit is calculated.